# What are some good ways to delete files with blank(invisible) names?

Tags: bash, filesystems

I discovered some files with blank names in my code repository, but I don't know how to find them all and delete them.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have access to the `find` command,

```
find . -regex ".*\/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*" -exec rm {} \;
```

If you'd like to check before actually deleting,

```
$ mkdir -p c/d # make some empty filenames
$ touch " " " b" "a b"
$ touch "c/ " "c/ b" "c/a b"
$ touch "c/d/ "
$ touch "c/d/  "
# echo the filenames with markings
$ find . -regex ".*\/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*" -exec echo '{}<blank' \;
./ <blank
./c/ <blank
./c/d/ <blank
./c/d/  <blank
```

Note: To my surprise, this even works with full-width spaces.

Comment: this also brings up files with space in their names, so I try to change the `name` parameter to `"^[[:space:]]*$"`, but this time I got no result.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic Thanks for pointing out. That pattern matched filenames like ` b` . See my updated answer; it excludes filenames like `c/ b` and `c/a b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-b` option of `ls` to find non printable characters eg `ls -b`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-regex` option to find:

```
touch " " "  a  b"
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex "^.*/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*$" -ls
# find . -maxdepth 1 -regex "^.*/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*$" -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the followwing:

```
for i in [^a-zA-Z0-9]* 
do
  ls -l "$i"
done
```

You may need to fiddle with the globbing pattern to find just the files with bad names.
When you like what you see, you can change the ls -l to the command that removes the files.

Comment: that would remove files that are named with other characters.

Comment: Changed it to a safe algoritm.

Comment: The pattern [[:space:]]* will match files that begin with a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works on Ubuntu 10.10):

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*[[:space:]][^/]*'  -print
```

Notes:

- I found the menagerie of regex types confusing and poorly documented.
- Specifying `-regextype posix-egrep` worked for me, YMMV.
- This regex matches `./foo bar`, but it does *not* match `./foo bar/baz`, because the blank is followed by a `/`.

To remove the files, use the `-exec rm {} ;` option; remember to use quotes (or backslashes) to protect against interpretation by the shell:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*[[:space:]][^/]*' -exec rm -f '{}' ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today. What worked for me to eliminate a file with blank name was to:

List the files with their inode numbers

```
ls -li
```

Remove the file by its inum

```
find -inum XXX -exec rm {} \;
```